# Measuring angle position of a pedal

Tags: sensor, voltage-divider

I am developing a electronic throttle control system for FSAE, and by rules of FSAE, I need to have 2 or more potentiometers to measure the position of my pedal. I've decided to use a rotary pot both ends of the pedal, but I am having trouble finding a 3rd potentiometer to use.

Is there any other sensors that can be used to measure angle position that would fit on(or in!) a metal axle? The issue I have is both ends of the axle are already being used by the 2 rotary pots.

Comment: My apologies for not putting volume: 0.5 inch diameter cylinder x 4 inch long would be a good approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided any volume information but that comes downto specific part choice. One technology to look into is a [Rotary Variable Differential Transformer (RVDT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_variable_differential_transformer) the angular equivalent of an LVDT

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you need binary precision (true/false) hall effect sensors with some magnets would be great.
To get more precision you can try texas instruments inductance-to-digital converters. To use it you only need some metal with decreasing  thickness with distance.